# MYSQL null value interfereing with C# application

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

Okay so what I'm doing is writing a WPF program that has textboxes bound to a MySQL table.

**[IMAGE REMOVED - PERSONAL DETAILS DISPLAYED]**

Now if I run, enter details, leave some blank as above and click save then the information is saved into the mysql as expected. How ever the default **NULL** value is removed and the cell is left blank, which is basically what I want.

now if I open the database directly in MYSQL and enter another record there, blank fields are left with **NULL** value. The **NULL* value go away if you type something and then erase them in the database I've noticed.

**[IMAGE REMOVED - PERSONAL DETAILS DISPLAYED]**

now normally this wouln't really be a problem but i keep getting this error everytime I click **NEXT** which is supposed to bring up the next record
Error msg: data is Null. this method or property cannot be called on Null values.
The funny part is the query seems to work fine when run directly in MySQL.

Here's the code for the next button:

```
//next button command
private void next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //MySQL connection credentials
    string sqlcon = "datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = Avalisque";
    //Query
    string query = "select * from clients.parent where tag = (select min(tag) from users.login where tag > '" + this.tag.Text + "' );";

    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(sqlcon);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
    MySqlDataReader rdr;

    //Excecution
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            //String declarations
            string stag = rdr.GetInt32("tag").ToString();
            string snumber = rdr.GetInt32("tag").ToString();
            string smember = rdr.GetInt32("member").ToString();
            string sstatus = rdr.GetString("status");

            string sfirst = rdr.GetString("first_name");
            string ssecond = rdr.GetString("second_name");
            string sthird = rdr.GetString("third_name");
            string sfourth = rdr.GetString("surname");

            string sdob = rdr.GetString("dob");
            string sgender = rdr.GetString("gender");

            string scell = rdr.GetString("cell");
            string shome = rdr.GetString("home");
            string swork = rdr.GetString("work");
            string semail = rdr.GetString("email");

            string sdoc = rdr.GetString("doc");
            string seligible = rdr.GetString("eligible");
            string sreason = rdr.GetString("denial_reason");
            string sother = rdr.GetString("other");

            string sclaim = rdr.GetString("claims");
            string srisk = rdr.GetString("risk");
            string sowing = rdr.GetString("owing");
            string spaid = rdr.GetString("paid");

            // Binding strings to textboxes
            tag.Text = stag;
            number.Text = stag;
            member.Text = smember;
            status.Text = sstatus;

            first_name.Text = sfirst;
            second_name.Text = ssecond;
            third_name.Text = sthird;
            surname.Text = sfourth;

            dob.Text = sdob;
            gender.Text = sgender;

            cell.Text = scell;
            home.Text = shome;
            work.Text = swork;
            email.Text = semail;

            doc.Text = sdoc;
            eligible.Text = seligible;
            reason.Text = sreason;
            other.Text = sother;
       }

       con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
}
```

If I save a record using the datagrid in the C# application the **NULL** value remains still.
Is there a way to ensure the **NULL** value is not given to blank cells by default? How do the textboxes do it anyways? I have tried right clicking the table -> Alter table -> erasing null from the default column but it does nothing.

I the datagrid will be used a lot to insert records but if the textboxes can't be used to browse through them then... I think you get the picture by now. Any way to solve this? Any alternatives if not?

Comment: You can multiple solutions here : change your database structure to not allow your char columns to be null. You can set their default value to '' (empty string). Another solution is to manage it directly in your code, for example : `email.Text = semail ?? String.Empty;`.

Comment: easiest way is to alter the column default to `''` instead of null so you don't have to change the code. `ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE columnname columnname VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL`

Comment: BTW you should not set your input values directly like that `cell.Text = scell;`. You should use WPF binding : have a look at [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264923.aspx)

Comment: Have removed the images and personal data was shown. Flagging for mod attention too.

Comment: The exception message is still the same: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the each column value before fetching the `string` value or may be design a function as,

```
public static string GetString(SqlDataReader reader, string colName)
{
    if (reader[colName] == DBNull.Value)
        return string.Empty;
    else
        return (string)reader[colName];            
}
```

and use it as,

```
string sclaim = GetString(rdr,"claims");
```

**EDIT** Some where you are also casting the `int` to `string` so you can use a single function,

```
public static string GetColumnValueAsString(SqlDataReader reader, string colName)
{
    if (reader[colName] == DBNull.Value)
        return string.Empty;
    else
        return reader[colName].ToString();        
}
```

and then you can access all the columns, with a single function without worrying about `null`.

```
    string stag = GetColumnValueAsString(rdr, "tag");
    string snumber = GetColumnValueAsString(rdr, "tag");
    string smember = GetColumnValueAsString(rdr, member);
    string sstatus = GetColumnValueAsString(rdr,"status");
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch mate. Really. For the most part it works actually.It moves onto the next record as I asked which is basically the solution I asked for. Thing is the darn error message keeps poping up everytime I click on next. Any clue why?

Comment: Every time I click on next when I get to a record typed in through the datagrid or MySQL table editor I meant to say...

Comment: @Offer can you paste the stack trace or exception details that you get in exception

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your strings are not initialized, they are literally NULL values, my advice is this:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue)) stringValue ="";
```

Apply that to your strings, and it should make the issue go away.

Comment: Much gratitude Aydin. Applied the solutions in order though and dbw worked 1st and well at that. Gave him his credit but thanks non the less.